# rpm spec file - How to specify multiple package archtypes in the requires

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

**What I have in spec**
Requires: lftp zsh boost db4 db4-devel

**What I need in spec**
Requires: lftp zsh boost db4 db4-devel db4-cxx.i686 db4-devel.i686

But the x.i686 doesn't work. When I try to install the package with yum, it just says Error: Package: blah Requires: db4-devel.i686 db4-cxx.i686

Is there a way to install both x86_64 and i686 packages using the Requires: in the spec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late, but  i'll just leave this here:

```
www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/ArchDependencies
```

So, should looks like:

```
Requires: db4-devel(x86-32) db4-cxx(x86-32)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the spec file goes, what about:

```
Requires: db4.x86_64 db4.i686
```

As for the yum error, that sounds like yum can't find a package called `db4.i686`.  Can you find that package with `yum search`?